UnsatisfiedLinkError in KMeansDAL during training with OneCCL in OAP MLlib
I encountered an error while running KMeans clustering with OAP MLlib, specifically when using the KMeansDAL implementation. The application fails with an UnsatisfiedLinkError, which points to an issue with loading the native CCL library in OneCCL$.c_init.
Here’s the full error trace:
`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.intel.oap.mllib.OneCCL$.c_init(IILjava/lang/String;Lcom/intel/oap/mllib/CCLParam;)I
at com.intel.oap.mllib.OneCCL$.c_init(Native Method)
at com.intel.oap.mllib.OneCCL$.init(OneCCL.scala:32)
at com.intel.oap.mllib.clustering.KMeansDALImpl.$anonfun$train$4(KMeansDALImpl.scala:71)
at com.intel.oap.mllib.clustering.KMeansDALImpl.$anonfun$train$4$adapted(KMeansDALImpl.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2(RDD.scala:907)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$2$adapted(RDD.scala:907)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)`

Environment:
OAP MLlib version: 1.6.0
Spark version: 3.3.3
OneAPI CCL version: 2021.8.0
Java version: OpenJDK 8
The native libraries for CCL are installed under /opt/intel/oneapi/ccl/2021.8.0/lib/cpu/ and /opt/intel/oneapi/ccl/2021.8.0/lib/cpu_gpu_dpcpp/.
Java environment variables seem correctly configured.
Could you please assist in resolving this issue? Thank you!
